# Drawing the complex equation $|\text{Re }z|<|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am skipping the calculation here. (I can provide if anyone needs to see). I think it will be the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ excluding the $x$ axis. Am I right? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: off the bat...yes

Comment: @imranfat Thanks a lot ...........

Answer (score 0):

Consider the mapping $z \mapsto x + iy$. Then:

$$|\Re{z}| < |z| \implies |x| < |x + iy| \implies \sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

(a) The equation is only equal when $y=0$. (b) Now notice that $y^2$ is always positive, then $\sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ for any $y \neq 0$. By (a) the $x$-axis is excluded from the set of points and by (b) every other point is included.